# JDBC gives a lot of errors in eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc

[image]

As you see there's a lot of errors in the project!
However, the program runs well :) but I want to remove this errors or at least know its reason

Comment: Clean the project. `Project-->Clean`. Rebuild.

Comment: Don't put a screenshot of your IDE.  Copy/paste the text of the error messages.

Comment: open the problems window in eclipse to see it exactly. Windows -> show views -> general - > problems

Comment: Did you just copy the source files into your project? That's horrible...

Comment: Check the bulidPath too

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse you have the [Problems](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcprbview.htm) tab available on one of the panes, this should list the reasons for all the errors in your screenshot.  You need to look at that list which will explain why each error is present and then investigate them from there.

"To add the Problems view to the current perspective, Window > Show View > Other... > General > Problems."

Answer (score 1):

I think you extracted the jar file from mysql driver and then imported the extracted files into the project. Instead, create a new project and add the jar in the project and add them later in the build path of the project.

See it:
http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java)